# c++ Warning: Clang-Tidy: Repeated branch in conditional chain

Tags: c++, c++14, clion, clang-tidy

Can you help me how to avoid the warning in this code ...

> Warning: Clang-Tidy: Repeated branch in conditional chain

```cpp
HubInterface *getFreeHub() {
        HubInterface *freeHub = nullptr;
        while (freeHub == nullptr) {
            for (auto hub : this->getHubList()) {
                if (freeHub == nullptr) {
                    freeHub = hub;
                } else if (hub->getStatus() == STATUS_READY &&
                           hub->getBusyNodes().size() < freeHub->getBusyNodes().size()) {
                    freeHub = hub;
                }
            }
            sleep(5);
        }
        return freeHub;
    }
```

*Warning provided by CLion IDE*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The warning is about the fact that you are doing the same thing in your `if` and `else if` branches, which is `freeHub = hub;`

```
if (freeHub == nullptr) {
    freeHub = hub;
} else if (hub->getStatus() == STATUS_READY &&
           hub->getBusyNodes().size() < freeHub->getBusyNodes().size()) {
    freeHub = hub; // same as above, what is the point?
}
```

I suppose you could rewrite it as a single condition but it's getting a bit scary:

```
if (freeHub == nullptr ||
    (hub->getStatus() == STATUS_READY &&
     hub->getBusyNodes().size() < freeHub->getBusyNodes().size())) {
    freeHub = hub;
}
```

Comment: there ara many hubs, I need a hub with the status of "READY" and the least number of occupied nodes...

Comment: @mat.twg, I understand, but according to your code you don't check those conditions when `freeHub` is null, right?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was updated code, now all seems ok... also additional conditions added.